# Keeping only common columns in three data sets

Tags: r

I have three data sets. Each data set having different dimensions. But each data set have some common column names. Now I want three data sets all having same column names.

```
df1<-data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
names(df1)<-c("a","b","c")
df2<-data.frame(c(3,2,3),c(4,6,6))
names(df2)<-c("a","b")
df3<-data.frame(c(2,2,3),c(8,5,6),c(7,8,9),c(13,12,11))
names(df3)<-c("a","b","c","d")
## resulting data frames should be
res_df1<-data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
res_df2<-data.frame(c(3,2,3),c(4,6,6))
res_df3<-data.frame(c(2,2,3),c(8,5,6))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can put all the dataframes in a list, use `Reduce` to get common column names and then subset the common columns from each.

```
list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
cols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(list_df, names))
final_df <- lapply(list_df, `[`, cols)
final_df

#[[1]]
#  a b
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 6

#[[2]]
#  a b
#1 3 4
#2 2 6
#3 3 6

#[[3]]
#  a b
#1 2 8
#2 2 5
#3 3 6
```

If you want to access individual dataframes from this list you can do `final_df[[1]]`, `final_df[[2]]` and so on.

Comment: Thanks sir, if we have some na elements in any dataset

Comment: @jeetkamal `NA`s should not matter here since we are subsetting only based on names of the columns.